# MySQL parse XML to table with unknown number or rows and no column names?

Tags: mysql, xml, parsing

If it was any other programming language I could usually work it out in no time. But after spending 6 hours flat "googlling" how to do it and having a few arrogant people tell me I should "google it", as If I haven't spent half my morning doing that. I still can not work out how to do this.

The problem is every example seems to be either SQL not MYSQL and I have had a very hard time converting it to MYSQL, failed at that. Or other examples are for fixed column names and a number of columns.

The XML will be like this:

```
<root>
<interest> name of interest 1</interest>
<interest> name of interest 2</interest>
<interest> name of interest 3</interest>
<interest> name of interest 4</interest>
</root>
```

Not that complicated. But despite this I seem to have had no luck working out how to do this.

I know I could accomplish the same task using an IN clause and dynamically generating the SQL statement. But I want to do this properly and efficiently using a stored procedure.

Comment: What is the structure of your table? Are you trying to use MySQL's unique command, `LOAD XML INFILE`? AFAIK, unlike other RDMS's (Oracle, SQL, Postgres), MySQL does not have a dedicated XML syntax language.